# Windows: how to switch back from Scipy 0.14 to Scipy 0.8

Tags: python, scipy, nltk

I need MaxEnt for text classification in NLTK. Apparently this has been deprecated for Scipy after Scipy 0.8. As I really need to use MaxEnt and I don't understand what I found online about using scikit learn for the topic of text classification, I would like to switch back from Scipy 0.14 to Scipy 0.8.

I am using Windows and I don't really get how to do the switch back.

Can anybody help me out? Thank you!

Comment: How did you install scipy originally?

Comment: @TheBlackCat I downloaded Anaconda 3. If you need any more information, I'd be happy to provide it

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v0.8.0

Comment: Just upgrade to a newer NLTK version.